# Placing a control over a mapview iOS 7 using storyboards

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview, uistoryboard

I'm trying to place a button over a mapview. In storyboard I have it as the last control in the view hierarchy, the map view still covers it up. I've tried adding this line in my viewDidLoad method to bring my button view to the front but it doesnt seem to work either

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.flagButton];
```

anyone have any idea why this wouldnt be working? the map view covers most of the screen, and I want to place a few buttons on top of the map, but so far can't get them to show up, they are under it every time.

Comment: did you figure out the solution?

Comment: nope. ended up just using some ui bar button items instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this by making my view as subview of map view.

first,

```
self.view = self.gmsMapView;
```

then,

```
[self.gmsMapView addSubview:_myBtnView];
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I'm answering for the sake of someone facing the same problem.

I was having the same issue, then I found a solution, and is as follows:

First, open your project and go to your StoryBoard then click on "Show Document Outline" switch that is on bottom left very small switch. After that select your "Scene" that you are having problems with then click "View". Find your MKMapView object and drag it up until you reach the first row. This will make your MKMapView object (or any other) "the first in a layer" so to speak.

I hope someone will find this helpful. 
E

Answer (score 1):

I was using storyboards and was not seeing the button. I had to set the MKMapView to hidden until the button was displayed and in position. Then I set the MKMapView to visible.

Here are the steps I had to take in the interface builder to get my button to show

1. Create a UIViewController which contains a view
2. Add an MKMapView and set constraints

[image: shows an MKMapView in a view controller in IB]

2. Add UIButton in the same view as the MKMapView, set the image and text, whatever is applicable. If MKMapView disappear when you try to resize or move the button, the map view has just set its width and height to zero.  Enter new values in the Size Inspector for the map view and it will resize back. Or you can move the button elsewhere off the MKMapView and then move the button back to where you want it.
3. The important part is to set constraints for the UIButton.  I also had to set the MKMapView hidden until I got the size and placement right and then set it back to visible.

[image: shows a UIButton with its constraints in IB]

Here's how it looks in the simulator

[image: a running app showing the map with a button on top]

Comment: I love this answer @Maria - but when I try to drag a UIButton onto my view containing the Map view item the button item just replaces the Map item.   Its there some setting in Xcode 8 I need to change to get two views on the same scene?    Or, I see that you have a Container View - does that have to be present to get the button and map in the same storyboard scene?

My document outline looks like
`Detail Scene (the scene name)<line break>
  ( ) Detail <line break>
       Map View<line break>
       [<] Detail  (navigation bar stuff.)<line break>
           Left Nav Button Items...
`

Comment: @malsmith In the example above, the map is not in the container.  The container is the view that slides out when pressing the button.  You can see that the map is in a UIView inside  the UIViewController scene.  I just tried on Xcode 8 and I can drag a button on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a subview to an `MKMapView` via the storyboard. Add it as a sibling view instead.

Edit: Your map view should also be a subview of the root view (i.e. self.view) for this to work.

Comment: The mapview and my button are both children of the root view.

Comment: @StonePreston They should both be at the same indentation level in your document inspector (to indicate they are siblings). Is this what you're seeing? Also flagButton should be below your mapView in this hierarchy.

Comment: yes thats what I am seeing. They are both the same indentation, and my button is below the map view

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues and I did the following:

- Made sure both the map view and the button are at the same level in the view hierarchy, I accomplished this by creating a View that both the map view and button were children of.
- Made sure the button is dragged below the map view in the left gutter of the storyboard (so it is actually rendered on top).
- Made sure there were valid constraints for the button.

The only thing new that hasn't already been mentioned was double-checking the constraints, and that appeared to resolve it for me.  Hope that helps.